# Remove media button from the custom post type support editor

Tags: post-type-support

Below code removes the medial button from other editors as well..

how to remove the editor from the post type support editor

```
   add_action('admin_head', 'remove_mediabuttons');


function remove_mediabuttons()
{
    global $post;

    if($post->post_type == 'custom_post_type' && current_user_can('edit_post') )
    {
        remove_action( 'media_buttons', 'media_buttons' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Which other editors is the code removing the button from? I ran it and it doesn't remove the button from the Page or Post editors.

Comment: I have custom meta box with video upload and editor.. I am trying to remove the upload video button from the custom post type

Comment: In your question you said `"code removes the [media] button from other editors"`. Which other editors is it removing the button from? Are they other Custom Post Type editors?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is that it removes the button from _other editors on the same page_. Is that right?

Comment: Yes..there are other editors on the same page..